# Como invocar 2 funciones en Javascript, AJAX y PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy haciendo un programita el cual cuando el usuario de clic, este invoque 2 funciones que hacen cosas diferentes.

Cuando doy clic se envían ambas (ya lo verifiqué en las herramientas de desarrollador de Chrome) y de hecho responden correctamente ambas al PHP, sin embargo cuando regresan, solo me aparece el segundo div lleno, el primero no se llena.

Intenté invocar la función 2 en la 1, pero ahora se ejecuta la primera y no la segunda.

Lo mandé a llamar justo debajo de esta línea:

```
            document.getElementById("employee").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
             }function getInteractions(str);
     };
```

pero no funciono :'(

¿Me podrían recomendar que pueda hacer? Aquí esta parte de mi código

**JAVASCRIPT + AJAX**

```
function getEmployees(str) {

    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("employee").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("employee").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "getEmployees.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}



function getInteractions(strg) {
    if (strg == "") {
        document.getElementById("interaction").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("interaction").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "getInteractions.php?a=" + strg, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="theid" name="theid" placeholder="Escribe tu número de empleado" />
<button onclick="getEmployees($(#theid).val());getInteractions($(#theid).val());">Enviar</button>
<div id="employee"></div>
<div id="interaction"></div>
```

Comment: una duda, ya que usas jQuery, ¿por que no haces el ajax con jQuery directamente? ¿es alguna clase de ejercicio o aprendizaje?

Comment: Hola, perdón, no es un ejercicio, sigo estudiando pero me dieron la oportunidad de desarrollar algo en mi empresa. ¿Crees poder ayudarme?

Comment: el código html que has adjuntado no es correcto, no puede corresponder al problema que mencionas.

Comment: a mi me funcionó perfecto al ejecutar dos archivos php en la misma función javascript con diferentes ajax, pero solo cuando se envian al tiempo, si se necesita envair una tras otra se usa **async: false,** dentro del ajax como indican anteriormente

Answer (score 2):

intenta utilizar la función when de jquery. El siguiente código fue como yo resolví el mismo problema que tienes, necesitaba llenar algunos catálogos y consultar la información actual para que el usuario pudiera editar los datos.

```
    $.when(
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "localhost/sistema",
            async: false,
            username: "cd",
            password: "****",
            success: function(data) {
                distritos = data;
            }
        }),
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "localhost/sistema",
            async: false,
            username: "cd",
            password: "****",
            success: function(data) {
                reclusorios = data;
            }
        }),
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "localhost/sistema",
            async: false,
            username: "cd",
            password: "****",
            success: function(data) {
                delitos = data;
            }
        }),

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "localhost/sistema",
            async: false,
            username: "cd",
            password: "****",
            success: function(data) {
                datos = data;
            }
        })
    ).done(function() {
       // escribir html o lo que necesites...
}
```

En el done ya tendrías todos los datos que consultas con las peticiones AJAX y que guardas en tus variables, en mi caso son delitos,etc.

Answer (score 1):

Haz olvidado poner las comillas en el `id` del elemento, en ambos casos.

Debes reemplazar, `$(#theid)` por `$('#theid')`,

Ejemplo...

```
<button onclick="getEmployees($('#theid').val()); getInteractions($('#theid').val());">
   Enviar
</button>
```

Aquí te dejo [una demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/2IrZsMPSwuOjbKh4ep8x?p=preview), no puedo ponerla aquí por que los stack snippets [no soportan ajax](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278311/add-resources-to-code-snippet).

Comment: Si, fue un error de dedo, de hecho, con o sin comas, sigo con el problema, no puedo invocar a las 2 funciones en un click.

Comment: Fíjate bien en el ejemplo que deje, tu solución funciona bien.

Comment: Gracias, eso ya lo había probado, de hecho si funciona si ponemos fijo el resultado en JS. Mi problema radica en que, cuando doy click al botón, se arma todo el xmlhttp y se envía la primera y regresa con un resultado y lo plasma en el div correspondiente, después lanza la segunda función regresa con la respuesta y lo plancha en el div correspondiente a la segunda función, per oel resultado del primer div desaparece y solo queda el segundo. :(

Comment: No es así, se lanzan en paralelo. Y llegan de forma asincrónica . Cuando haces send, la función retorna de forma inmediata

Comment: asegurate de no tener otra cosa (css, javascript) que este alterando el resultado, con esas comillas el codigo funciona bien.

Answer (score 0):

El error se presenta debido a que la repuesta que obtienes de AJAX se esta ejecutando de forma asincrona, por lo tanto se debe colocar **async** en **false** dentro de tu AJAX
**async: false**

Answer (score 0):

efectivamente, como dice @fancer el problema es que estás haciendo llamadas simultáneas a esas funciones. Te va a dar errores si finaliza primero la llamada que depende de la otra.
Pon a false el último parámetro de la función:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "getInteractions.php?a=" + false);
```